# How do I pass a variable in a method? I am trying to access a json dictionary associated with a button id variable

Tags: javascript, json

I am using javascript mapping libraries to make a web map.

I have buttons that will toggle different layers and basemaps on/off. When a button is pressed, a unique `buttonId` is passed to this function. From there, I would like to reference a json dictionary that pulls the layers and basemaps for the relevant `buttonId` and shows that information on the map.

In my sample code below, there is an issue with `obj.name.buttonId.show`, whereas `obj.name.button1.show` would return a valid value. How do I resolve this? In other words, how do I pass the variable `buttonId` in a method to retrieve its parameters?
Code:

```
function(arg) { 

    var json = '{"name":{"button1": {"show": "streets", "basemap": "dark-gray"}, "button2": {"show": "railroads", "basemap": "terrain"}, "button3": {"show": "rivers", "basemap": "terrain"} }}';
    var obj = dojo.fromJson(json);
    buttonId = arg.target.id

        if (obj.name == buttonId){
            this.map.getLayer(obj.name.buttonId.show).show()
            this.map.setBasemap(obj.name.buttonId.basemap) 
        else
            pass
};
```

I am trying to avoid writing if/then statements for every button, hence why I am taking this approach.

Comment: Don't use JSON strings. Just create a simple object literal: `var obj = {nme: {button1:…, button2:…}};`

Comment: @Bergi, would the "..." be functions? Is this the best way if each button will have a very similar function--ie showing a particular layer and basemap? I want to avoid writing the same code for each button scenario

Comment: You could use any kind of value, including functions, but those values you currently have seem totally fine.